# Wiring a TCST2103

Tags: circuit-design

Any TCST2103 (optical sensor) module I bought is wired so the signal is HIGH when triggered and I need the direct opposite. Tried to find a place in the module to match the opposite voltage, but seems not to exist. Any idea how to wire the sensor, 3.3V logic so the output is HIGH when not triggered? Datasheet for quick access https://www.vishay.com/docs/81147/tcst2103.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at page 1 of the data sheet: -

[image]

You have two options: -

1. Output at emitter with resistor to 0 volts, collector to positive supply
2. Output at collector with resistor to positive supply, emitter to 0 volts

Decide which one you have and to get an inverted response, use the other.